# While working, How do you share codes, files between two devices?

Tags: file-sharing, instant

While working, I'm always having problems related to data sharing.

For example:

- I have a computer connected to the printer but my laptop is not and I want to print a file, how do I easily move that file to the printer computer?
- How to share a file from my mobile to laptop?

What I'm doing right now is moving the file using a USB disk, e-mail address  or facebook.

You as developers, what are you doing for such purposes?

Comment: You can just share a folder in the computer and connect to this folder using the network. And for the printer, you can share it in the computer and in the laptop do a printer discover and connect to it

Comment: it takes too much time to do the setup and sometimes I don't have access to local network, so I'm using now ziggs.io as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do is using network because its fast and safe.

But if I have a good internet connection I would suggest you to use [Ziggs.io - Smoothly Share Content Between Devices](https://ziggs.io).

The bad fact about Ziggs is that you need an internet connection to use it.

What I like about it that you don’t have to register, you can share files up to 500 MB per file and they don’t store messages.

More about Ziggs from their website:

> What is Ziggs?
>
> Ziggs is a platform that exists to facilitate peoples communications
>
> Ziggs is like a meeting point with your devices, it helps you to
> transfer contents between these devices smoothly.
>
> Drag-and-drop PDFs,
> images, videos, APK apps and other files directly into Ziggs.
>
> Messages
> are delivered directly from your device to the connected clients.
>
> Ziggs doesn't store any type of data and doesn't require your personal
> information.
>
> Ziggs uses smart solutions based on client-side to share channel conversation history with new clients.
>
> Exists channel clients will act as seeds, helps new clients to follow up with the conversation.

Comment: any idea how to use this website?

Comment: type any channel name in for example: myprintedfile22 and join that channel on your printer pc and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

I've built my own cloud for this exact function:

https://www.github.com/TheWlr9/LocalCloud

However, this question should've been posted on some forum page, and not Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thanks, nothing simpler?

Comment: Maybe look into ftp? Other than that, flash drives and e-mails.

Comment: Or sftp I should recommend